# NetworkX graph: ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to run some experiments on a NetworkX graph for research purposes. I am new to Python and graphs at all so I ran into a problem that I don't know how to solve. The code of my experiment is below.

```
def run_experiment(Graph, order, output_filename):

    # returns a list of the edges in decreasing order of their frequency
    decreasing_order_edges = sorted(Graph.edges(), key= lambda x: Graph.get_edge_data(*x)['weight'], reverse=True)

    if order == INCREASING_ORDER:
        # reverse the decreasing_order_egdes
        increasing_order_edges = decreasing_order_edges
        increasing_order_edges.reverse()
        run_edge_deletion_with_stats(Graph, increasing_order_edges, output_filename)
    elif order == DECREASING_ORDER:
        # maintain the decreasing order of the cooccurrence_freq_map
        run_edge_deletion_with_stats(Graph, decreasing_order_edges, output_filename)        
    elif order == RANDOM_ORDER:
        # randomly permute the decreasing_order_edges list
        random_order_edges = random.sample(decreasing_order_edges, len(decreasing_order_edges))
        run_edge_deletion_with_stats(Graph, random_order_edges, output_filename)


def write_stats_to_file(output_filename, stats_per_timestep, timestep):

    f = open(output_filename, "w+") # + <- indicates file
                                # should be created if
                                # it doesn't already exist
    f.write("TIMESTEP STATISTICS\n")
    f.write("timestep, diameter, num_sccs, max_scc_size")
    for stat in stats_per_timestep:
        f.write("%d, %d, %d, %f\n" %(timestep, stat[0][0], stat[0][1], stat[0][2]))
        print("%d, %d, %d, %f" % (timestep, stat[0][0], stat[0][1], stat[0][2]))
    f.close()



def run_edge_deletion_with_stats(Graph, edge_ordering, output_filename):
    stats_per_timestep = []
    timestep = 0

    ## print initial values for the graph
    print timestep, calculate_stats(Graph)

    num_deleted_edges = 0
    for edge, edge_weight in edge_ordering:
        u, v = edge       
        # delete one bidirectional edge
        Graph.remove_edge(u,v)

        num_deleted_edges += 1
        if num_deleted_edges % TIMESTEP_SEQUENCE == 0:
            timestep += 1
            timestep_stats = calculate_stats(Graph)
            print timestep, timestep_stats
            stats_per_timestep += [timestep_stats]

    write_stats_to_file(output_filename, stats_per_timestep, timestep)
```

When I run this code I get this error

```
Network contains 174 nodes
Network contains 1284 edges
running experiment with increasing order
0 [1.0, 174]
[[1.0, 174]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\...\src\graph_analysis\edge_removal_experiment.py", line 162, in <module>
run()
File "C:\Users\...\src\graph_analysis\edge_removal_experiment.py", line 151, in run
run_experiment(g, order = INCREASING_ORDER, output_filename = "edge_increasing_experiment.csv")
File "C:\Users\...\src\graph_analysis\edge_removal_experiment.py", line 49, in run_experiment
run_edge_deletion_with_stats(Graph, increasing_order_edges, output_filename)
File "C:\Users\...\src\graph_analysis\edge_removal_experiment.py", line 84, in run_edge_deletion_with_stats
u, v = edge       
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there are more variables than just 2.

```
x, y = (1, 2, 3)

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

So, your `decreasing_order_edges` is a list.

Check length of this list.